# Angularjs ng-repeat md-focus last element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-material

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" md-autofocus="$last">
<div>
 {{item}
</div>
<div>
```

The above code is in a md-dialog which has a vertical scroll .

The requirement is to scroll to the last element when item is added at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your own directive to do this,here is an example that can probably help you to this;

Basically, when a new item is added then the $anchorScroll service will be used to scroll to that specific element.

```
app.directive('scrollToLast', ['$location', '$anchorScroll', function($location, $anchorScroll){

  function linkFn(scope, element, attrs){
      $location.hash(attrs.scrollToLast);
      $anchorScroll();
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {

    },
    link: linkFn
  };

}]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/binoqavopa/18/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: angular material has an md-autofocus directive . can you give an example making that work ?   https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.10/api/directive/mdAutofocus

Comment: yes i know that but you cannot specifically focus on the element within ng-repeat its for input elements